# Plotting an integral where the integrand depends on the parameter values (`If`)

Tags: plotting, conditional

With my function $f(x)$ I would like to `Plot3D`

$\int_a^b f(x) dx$

with the parameter values $a \in [0,1]$ and $b \in [1,3]$. 
The challenging part has to do with my integrand, which is as follows

$f(x)=x$ if $a \leq b \leq 2a$,

$f(x)=x^2$ if $b > 2a$.

My Mathematica code is as follows:

```
f = Integrate[If[a <= b <= 2\ a, x, x^2], {x, a, b}]; Flatten[Table[{a, b, f}, {a, 0, 1, .1}, {b, 1, 3, .1}], 1]
```

When I run this, I get results that look correct if the condition is 'true', but if the condition is 'false' I get results with the associated integral value `Undefined`. I wonder if there is anything wrong with my code.
Thanks!

Comment: Didn't realize this until just now, and this applies to the question itself, but could you double check your conditions?  Because $a \leq b \leq 2b$ is always true in this region, and the condition in your code looks like you might have wanted `a <= b <= 2 a`.

Comment: @ThatGravityGuy: Yes, you are right, that was a typo! I have corrected it. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `If` method

You can use `If` to get the job done

```
f = If[a <= b <= 2 a, x, x^2]
ifmethod = Flatten[Table[{A, B, Integrate[f /. {a -> A, b -> B}, {x, A, B}]}, {A, 0, 1, .1}, {B,  1, 3, .1}], 1]
```

The key here is to tell `f` what `a,b` are with the replacement *before* the integration takes place so that you get the right form (e.g. $x$ or $x^2$).

## `Piecewise` function method

```
f[a_, b_, x_] := Piecewise[{{x, a <= b <= 2 a}, {x^2, b > 2 a}}]
piecewisemethod = Flatten[Table[{a, b, Integrate[f[a, b, x], {x, a, b}]}, {a, 0, 1, .1}, {b, 1, 3, .1}], 1]
```

## Comparison

```
ifmethod == piecewisemethod
```

> True

Comment: `If` is a procedural construct, mostly useful for numeric computations. Symbolic functions like `Integrate` and `Solve` have no methods to "reason" about what the result of a procedure might be. So, when using symbolic methods, avoid `If` and use things like `Piecewise` or the `Heaviside` functions.

Comment: @JohnDoty: Thanks!

Comment: Dear That Gravity Guy, your answer was very helpful for which I really appreciate. I am applying your answer to a more complicated task. If you allow, may I ask your help once more? My question can be found here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202092/3d-plot-a-maximization-of-a-definite-integral-where-the-integrand-changes-depend