# 3D-plot of a maximization of a definite integral

Tags: plotting, conditional, mathematical-optimization

I'm applying the answer (`If` method) suggested by 'ThatGravityGuy' in this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202034/plotting-an-integral-where-the-integrand-depends-on-the-parameter-values-if) in a more complicated case.

Consider my objective function (pardon its formidable expression):

$f=\int _d^{d+k r}\int _k^s A dydx+ \int _{d+k r}^s\int _k^s B dydx+ \int _d^{d+k r}\int _{\frac{d+k r-x}{r}}^k D dydx+ \int _{d+k r}^s\int _0^k E dydx$

where

$A = \frac{(1-t) (r (x-k)+k r+(1-r) x -J)-(d-t)}{s^2}$ if $A > 0$, while $A=0$ if $A\leq 0$,

$B = \frac{(1-t) (r (x-k)+k r+(1-r) x-J)-(d-t)}{s^2}$  if $B > 0$, while $B=0$ if $B\leq 0$,

$D = \frac{(1-t) (r (x-k)+(1-r) x+r y-J)-(d-t)}{s^2}$ if $D > 0$, while $D=0$ if $D\leq 0$,

$E = \frac{(1-t) (r (x-k)+(1-r) x+r y-J)-(d-t)}{s^2}$ if $E > 0$, while $E=0$ if $E\leq 0$,

$J =c \left(\frac{(q-1) \left(d^2+k^2 r\right)}{s^2}+\frac{d s+\frac{k^2 r}{2}}{s^2}\right)-\frac{(1-d) \left(d s+\frac{k^2 r}{2}\right)}{s^2}$

I would like to maximize my objective function $f$ with respect to $r$ and $k$ and `Plot3D` them, i.e. the maximum value of $f$, and the corresponding $r$ and $k$, against $c \in [0,1]$ and $q \in [1,2]$ under the following parameter values and constraints: $s=2$, $d=0.8$, $t=0$, $0 \leq k<d$, $0 \leq r \leq 1$, $0\leq c \leq 1$, $1 \leq q \leq 2$, $cq \leq 1$.

My Mathematica Code is as follows (Since `C`, `D`, and `E` are protected letters, I'm starting with unprotecting them):

```
s = 2; d = 0.8; t = 0; 
J = -(((1 - d) ((k^2 r)/2 + d s))/s^2) + c (((-1 + q) (d^2 + k^2 r))/s^2 + ((k^2 r)/2 + d s)/s^2);  
A = If[(((1 - r)*x + r*(x - k) + r*y - J)*(1 - t) - (d - t))/s^2 > 0, (((1 - r)*x + r*(x - k) + r*y - J)*(1 - t) - (d - t))/s^2, 0]; 
B = If[(((1 - r)*x + r*(x - k) + r*k - J)*(1 - t) - (d - t))/s^2 > 0, (((1 - r)*x + r*(x - k) + r*k - J)*(1 - t) - (d - t))/s^2, 0]; 
D1 = If[(((1 - r)*x + r*(x - k) + r*y - J)*(1 - t) - (d - t))/s^2 > 0, (((1 - r)*x + r*(x - k) + r*y - J)*(1 - t) - (d - t))/s^2, 0]; 
E1 = If[(((1 - r)*x + r*(x - k) + r*k - J)*(1 - t) - (d - t))/s^2 > 0, (((1 - r)*x + r*(x - k) + r*k - J)*(1 - t) - (d - t))/s^2, 0]; 
max = Flatten[Table[{C1, Q, MaxValue[{Integrate[A /. {c -> C1, q -> Q}, {x, d, d + r*k}, {y, (d + r*k - x)/r, k}] + Integrate[B /. {c -> C1, q -> Q}, {x, d, d + r*k}, {y, k, s}] + Integrate[D1 /. {c -> C1, q -> Q}, {x, d + r*k, s}, {y, 0, k}] + Integrate[E1 /. {c -> C1, q -> Q}, {x, d + r*k, s}, {y, k, s}], 0 <= C1 <= 1, 1 <= Q <= 2, C1*Q <= 1, 0 <= k < d, 0 <= r <= 1}, {k, r}]}, {C1, 0, 1, .1}, {Q, 1, 2, .1}], 1]; 
maxk = Flatten[Table[{C1, Q, k /. Last@Maximize[{Integrate[A /. {c -> C1, q -> Q}, {x, d, d + r*k}, {y, (d + r*k - x)/r, k}] + Integrate[B /. {c -> C1, q -> Q}, {x, d, d + r*k}, {y, k, s}] + Integrate[D1 /. {c -> C1, q -> Q}, {x, d + r*k, s}, {y, 0, k}] + Integrate[E1 /. {c -> C1, q -> Q}, {x, d + r*k, s}, {y, k, s}], 0 <= C1 <= 1, 1 <= Q <= 2, C1*Q <= 1, 0 <= k < d, 0 <= r <= 1}, {k, r}]}, {C1, 0, 1, .1}, {Q, 1, 2, .1}], 1]; 
maxr = Flatten[Table[{C1, Q, r /. Last@Maximize[{Integrate[A /. {c -> C1, q -> Q}, {x, d, d + r*k}, {y, (d + r*k - x)/r, k}] + Integrate[B /. {c -> C1, q -> Q}, {x, d, d + r*k}, {y, k, s}] + Integrate[D1 /. {c -> C1, q -> Q}, {x, d + r*k, s}, {y, 0, k}] + Integrate[E1 /. {c -> C1, q -> Q}, {x, d + r*k, s}, {y, k, s}], 0 <= C1 <= 1, 1 <= Q <= 2, C1*Q <= 1, 0 <= k < d, 0 <= r <= 1}, {k, r}]}, {C1, 0, 1, .1}, {Q, 1, 2, .1}], 1]; 
{ListPlot3D[max, AxesLabel -> {"c", "q", "f"}], ListPlot3D[maxk, PlotRange -> {0, 2}, AxesLabel -> {"c", "q", "k"}], ListPlot3D[maxr, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"c", "q", "r"}]}
```

This code is running forever. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**Alex Trounev**'s suggested approach is working! Here is the code:

```
s = 2; d = 0.8; t = 0;
J = -(((1 - d) ((k^2 r)/2 + d s))/s^2) + c (((-1 + q) (d^2 + k^2 r))/s^2 + ((k^2 r)/2 + d s)/s^2);
regA = ImplicitRegion[1/800 (-16 c (3 + 2 q) + 25 c k^2 (1 - 2 q) r + 8 (-18 + 25 x) + 5 r ((-40 + k) k + 40 y)) > 0 &&     d <= x <= d + r*k && (d + r*k - x)/r <= y <= k, {x, y}];
regB = ImplicitRegion[1/800 (-144 - 16 c (3 + 2 q) + 5 k^2 r + 25 c k^2 (1 - 2 q) r + 200 x) > 0 && d <= x <= d + r*k && k <= y <= s, {x, y}];
regD = ImplicitRegion[1/800 (-16 c (3 + 2 q) + 25 c k^2 (1 - 2 q) r + 8 (-18 + 25 x) + 5 r ((-40 + k) k + 40 y)) > 0 && d + r*k <= x <= s && 0 <= y <= k, {x, y}];
regE = ImplicitRegion[1/800 (-144 - 16 c (3 + 2 q) + 5 k^2 r + 25 c k^2 (1 - 2 q) r + 200 x) > 0 && d + r*k <= x <= s && k <= y <= s, {x, y}];
max = Flatten[Table[{c, q, MaxValue[{Integrate[(((1 - r) x + r (x - k) + r y - J) (1 - t) - (d - t))/s^2, {x, y} \[Element] regA] + Integrate[(((1 - r)*x + r*(x - k) + r*k - J)*(1 - t) - (d - t))/s^2, {x, y} \[Element] regB] Integrate[(((1 - r)*x + r*(x - k) + r*y - J)*(1 - t) - (d - t))/s^2, {x, y} \[Element] regD] + Integrate[(((1 - r)*x + r*(x - k) + r*k - J)*(1 - t) - (d - t))/s^2, {x, y} \[Element] regE], 0 <= c <= 1, 1 <= q <= 2, c*q <= 1, 0 <= k < d, 0 <= r <= 1}, {k, r}]}, {c, 0, 1, .1}, {q, 1, 2, .1}], 1];
maxk = Flatten[Table[{c, q, k /. Last@Maximize[{Integrate[(((1 - r) x + r (x - k) + r y - J) (1 - t) - (d - t))/s^2, {x, y} \[Element] regA] + Integrate[(((1 - r)*x + r*(x - k) + r*k - J)*(1 - t) - (d - t))/s^2, {x, y} \[Element] regB] + Integrate[(((1 - r)*x + r*(x - k) + r*y - J)*(1 - t) - (d - t))/s^2, {x, y} \[Element] regD] + Integrate[(((1 - r)*x + r*(x - k) + r*k - J)*(1 - t) - (d - t))/s^2, {x, y} \[Element] regE], 0 <= c <= 1, 1 <= q <= 2, c*q <= 1, 0 <= k < d, 0 <= r <= 1}, {k, r}]}, {c, 0, 1, .1}, {q, 1, 2, .1}], 1];
maxr = Flatten[Table[{c, q, r /. Last@Maximize[{Integrate[(((1 - r) x + r (x - k) + r y - J) (1 - t) - (d - t))/s^2, {x, y} \[Element] regA] + Integrate[(((1 - r)*x + r*(x - k) + r*k - J)*(1 - t) - (d - t))/s^2, {x, y} \[Element] regB] + Integrate[(((1 - r)*x + r*(x - k) + r*y - J)*(1 - t) - (d - t))/s^2, {x, y} \[Element] regD] + Integrate[(((1 - r)*x + r*(x - k) + r*k - J)*(1 - t) - (d - t))/s^2, {x, y} \[Element] regE], 0 <= c <= 1, 1 <= q <= 2, c*q <= 1, 0 <= k < d, 0 <= r <= 1}, {k, r}]}, {c, 0, 1, .1}, {q, 1, 2, .1}], 1];
{ListPlot3D[max, AxesLabel -> {"c", "q", "f"}], ListPlot3D[maxk, PlotRange -> {0, 2}, AxesLabel -> {"c", "q", "k"}], ListPlot3D[maxr, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"c", "q", "r"}]}
```

Comment: I would recommend using esc+dsD+esc double sided symbols—it is generally recommended to not unprotect and redefine the symbols you used, especially `D` and `E`. Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks, CA Trevillian! I tried, for example, both `esc+dsD+esc` and `\[DoubleStruckCapitalD]` to format, but didn't work. (They did work in Mathematica.) Do you know how to do that to format?

Comment: I'm not following, they work in Mathematica, and don't work where? You are doing this in Mathematica? The shortcuts you listed should work in Mathematica, as you stated. When you redefine those symbols, functions that rely on them can have issues. On the surface, this is what I gather is happening or what is causing issues.

Comment: @ppp Integrals are not calculated, so the optimization process does not end.

Comment: @CA Trevillian I mean 'not working' here in Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Alex Trounev: Thanks so much! Do you know which part is causing an error? Can you please help fix it?

Comment: @ppp (Replace first of all `C->C1, D->D1,E->E1` ) It is necessary for each integral to determine the region of integration, for example `reg1 = ImplicitRegion[1/4 (-(4/5) + k r + 1/20 (8/5 + (k^2 r)/2) - 
        c (1/4 (8/5 + (k^2 r)/2) + 1/4 (-1 + q) (16/25 + k^2 r)) + (1 - r) x + r (-k + x)) > 
     0 && d <= x <= d + r*k && (d + r*k - x)/r <= y <= k, {x, y}];`. Then instead of `Integrate[A...`  there will be `Integrate[(((1 - r) x + r (x - k) + r k - J) (1 - t) - (d - 
    t))/s^2, {x, y} \[Element] reg1]`. Then the integral is calculated.

Comment: @Alex Trounev: Your suggested approach is working! I have added the code. Thanks very much!

Comment: @ppp you're welcome!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96233/discussion-between-ppp-and-alex-trounev).