# Plotting a maximization of a definite integral

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, mathematical-optimization

I am applying Alex Trounev's approach suggested in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202092/3d-plot-of-a-maximization-of-a-definite-integral). It worked for the function in that post. But it is now not working for another, more complicated function.

My objective function is

$f=\int _{\frac{d-k r}{1-r}}^k\int _{\frac{d+r x-x}{r}}^k\text{AA}dydx+\int _{\frac{d-k r}{1-r}}^k\int _k^s\text{BB}dydx+\int _k^{d+k r}\int _{\frac{d+k r-x}{r}}^k\text{CC}dydx+\int _k^{d+k r}\int _k^s\text{DD}dydx+\int _{d+k r}^s\int _0^k\text{EE}dydx+\int _{d+k r}^s\int _k^s\text{FF}dydx$

where

$\text{AA}=\frac{(1-t) (-J+(1-r) x+r y)-(d-t)}{s^2}$ if $AA>0$, while $AA=0$ if $AA \leq 0$

$\text{BB}=\frac{(1-t) (-J+k r+(1-r) x)-(d-t)}{s^2}$ if $BB>0$, while $BB=0$ if $BB \leq 0$

$\text{CC}=\frac{(1-t) (-J+r (x-k)+(1-r) x+r y)-(d-t)}{s^2}$ if $CC>0$, while $CC=0$ if $CC \leq 0$

$\text{DD}=\frac{(1-t) (-J+r (x-k)+k r+(1-r) x)-(d-t)}{s^2}$ if $DD>0$, while $DD=0$ if $DD \leq 0$

$\text{EE}=\frac{(1-t) (-J+r (x-k)+(1-r) x+r y)-(d-t)}{s^2}$ if $EE>0$, while $EE=0$ if $EE \leq 0$

$\text{FF}=\frac{(1-t) (-J+r (x-k)+k r+(1-r) x)-(d-t)}{s^2}$ if $FF>0$, while $FF=0$ if $FF \leq 0$

$J=c \left(\frac{(q-1) \left(k^2 r ((r-3) r+1)+\frac{8 k r^2}{5}+\frac{16}{25} (1-2 r)\right)}{4 (r-1)^2}+\frac{\frac{8}{5} k (r-1)+k (k (r-3) r+k+4 r)-\frac{64}{25}}{8 (r-1)}\right)-\frac{\frac{8}{5} k (r-1)+k (k (r-3) r+k+4 r)-\frac{64}{25}}{40 (r-1)}$

I would like to maximize my objective function $f$ with respect to $r$ and $k$ and `Plot3D` them, i.e. the maximum value of $f$, and the corresponding $r$ and $k$, against $c \in [0,1]$ and $q \in [1,2]$ under the following parameter values and constraints: $s=2$, $d=0.8$, $t=0$, $d \leq k \leq 2$, $0 \leq r <d/k $, $0\leq c \leq 1$, $1 \leq q \leq 2$, $cq \leq 1$.

My Mathematica Code is as follows:

```
s = 2; d = 4/5; t = 0;
J=-((-(64/25) + 8/5 k (-1 + r) + k (k + 4 r + k (-3 + r) r))/(40 (-1 + r))) + c (((-1 + q) (16/25 (1 - 2 r) + (8 k r^2)/5 + k^2 r (1 + (-3 + r) r)))/(4 (-1 + r)^2) + (-(64/25) + 8/5 k (-1 + r) + k (k + 4 r + k (-3 + r) r))/(8 (-1 + r)));
AA = (((1 - r)*x + r*y - J)*(1 - t) - (d - t))/s^2; 
BB = (((1 - r)*x + r*k - J)*(1 - t) - (d - t))/s^2; 
CC = (((1 - r)*x + r*(x - k) + r*y - J)*(1 - t) - (d - t))/s^2; 
DD = (((1 - r)*x + r*(x - k) + r*k - J)*(1 - t) - (d - t))/s^2; 
EE = (((1 - r)*x + r*(x - k) + r*y - J)*(1 - t) - (d - t))/s^2; 
FF = (((1 - r)*x + r*(x - k) + r*k - J)*(1 - t) - (d - t))/s^2;
regAA = ImplicitRegion[AA > 0 && (d - r*k)/(1 - r) <= x <= k && (d + r*x - x)/r <= y <= k, {x, y}];
regBB = ImplicitRegion[BB > 0 && (d - r*k)/(1 - r) <= x <= k && k <= y <= s, {x, y}];
regCC = ImplicitRegion[CC > 0 && k <= x <= d + r*k && (d + r*k - x)/r <= y <= k, {x, y}];
regDD = ImplicitRegion[DD > 0 && k <= x <= d + r*k && k <= y <= s, {x, y}];
regEE = ImplicitRegion[EE > 0 && d + r*k <= x <= s && 0 <= y <= k, {x, y}];
regFF = ImplicitRegion[FF > 0 && d + r*k <= x <= s && k <= y <= s, {x, y}];
f = Integrate[AA, {x, y} \[Element] regAA] + Integrate[BB, {x, y} \[Element] regBB] + Integrate[CC, {x, y} \[Element] regCC] + Integrate[DD, {x, y} \[Element] regDD] + Integrate[EE, {x, y} \[Element] regEE] + Integrate[FF, {x, y} \[Element] regFF];
max = Flatten[Table[{c, q, MaxValue[{f, 0 <= c <= 1, 1 <= q <= 2, c*q <= 1, d <= k <= 2, 0 <= r*k < d}, {k, r}]}, {c, 0, 1, .1}, {q, 1, 2, .1}], 1];
maxk = Flatten[Table[{c, q, k /. Last@Maximize[{f, 0 <= c <= 1, 1 <= q <= 2, c*q <= 1, d <= k <= 2, 0 <= r*k < d}, {k, r}]}, {c, 0, 1, .1}, {q, 1, 2, .1}], 1];
maxr = Flatten[Table[{c, q, r /. Last@Maximize[{f, 0 <= c <= 1, 1 <= q <= 2, c*q <= 1, d <= k <= 2, 0 <= r*k < d}, {k, r}]}, {c, 0, 1, .1}, {q, 1, 2, .1}], 1];
{ListPlot3D[max, AxesLabel -> {"c", "q", "f"}], ListPlot3D[maxk, PlotRange -> {0, 2}, AxesLabel -> {"c", "q", "k"}], ListPlot3D[maxr, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"c", "q", "r"}]}
```

This code ran forever, so I had to abort it, and I got the following list of error messages along with some diagram results, which seem incomplete.

[image]

Comment: Running forever?  If you evaluate all the lines other than the last, does it terminate?

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1737790).

Comment: @Rohit Namjoshi: Yes, as it was urgent, I am seeking help everywhere possible. Please let me know if I have to delete one of them.

Comment: @mjw: In fact, when I stopped running, I got some messages and graph results. I have added them in the post.

Comment: You could try scaling down the problem (less gridpoints), check the timing, and then estimate how long it will take for the larger problem.

Comment: @Bill: Thanks for your suggestion. In fact, my original approach was relying on an explicit `Integrate[expression..]`, which however ran forever. So I had to use the current approach, and it worked here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202092/3d-plot-of-a-maximization-of-a-definite-integral

Comment: @mjw: Following your suggestion, I have scaled down the gridpoints to around one fifth of the original, and it is also taking 'forever'.

Comment: Which line(s) of code is it stalling at?  First we need to know this.  Thanks

Comment: This looks like the one:  `f = Integrate[AA, {x, y} \[Element] regAA] + ...
   Integrate[FF, {x, y} \[Element] regFF];`

Comment: I think Bill already pointed this out.

Comment: @mjw: Thanks for your comment! In fact, I wasn't able to figure that out... But let's say the one you pointed out is the culprit. Then what do I have to do with that? I would appreciate your help.

Comment: I think that you should try setting up each integral by providing the limits, rather than using `ImplicitRegion`.  You state in a comment that you tried that, and it took forever.  Perhaps post the code and we can all look at it.

Comment: @mjw: The code can be found in this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202092/3d-plot-of-a-maximization-of-a-definite-integral); it is the first code in that post. The challenge of this approach is how to deal with each integrand, which varies conditional on the parameter constraints. As you can see in the code, I used `If`. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You could use `If[A>0,A,0]` or perhaps `Max[A,0]`.

Comment: @mjw: Thanks! As you can see in the code of the previous post, I used `If[A>0,A,0]` there. I also tried `Max[A,0]` Both run forever.